# How to add an image in in the ArrayList.add(new?

Tags: image, arraylist, android-intent, android-imageview

Please Could you help me?
I am creating a guess game in Android Studio with image and options answers. My question is How to add an image into Array list?
[image: code].

[image]
In the imageView I tried to add image but it is not working.

Comment: you are passing asset drawble integer reference number .you shoud pass imageview instead.

Comment: `ImageView im=new ImageView(); im.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageView);new Guessmodal(im,.....)`(.... )means other parameter no change

Comment: Thank you so much but I got this issue "Cannot resolve constructor 'ImageView()'

Comment: `new ImageView (Context context)`  `context` you can get from activityclass or fragment class.you can use `new ImageView (this)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.